# What does the combination of !!~ do?

Tags: javascript

I have seen in a codebase instances of the (simplified version) of the following code:

//testIds is a calculated array of ids stored in a variable

```
let existence = tests.filter( (test) => return !!~testIds.indexOf(test.id) )
```

I have no idea what !!~ is, to me it looks like it's a more verbose way of saying:

```
testIds.indexOf(test.id) > 0
```

Can someone tell me what this is?

Comment: it checks if the value != -1

Comment: the `~` does a bitwise not, then the `!!` coalesces the value to a boolean, so you end up with the bitwise negation of your input, coalesced to its "truthy" representation